# Trouble compiling mono from source via cygwin on windows

Tags: compilation, mono, cygwin

I work off my **i:** drive

I've downloaded the following mono source file **mono-2.11.2.tar.bz2**
I've installed the windows version of mono v2.11.2 to **"I:\Mono-2.11.2"**

I installed cygwin as per the following instructions found on the following webpage http://shana.worldofcoding.com/en/mono_cygwin_tutorial.html

I replaced the **"make.exe"** with the one from the mono website as per instruction. I had to get one more file "cygintl-2.dll" which resides in cygwin package **libintl2/libintl2-0.12.1-3**

I added the following my .bashrc file. I had to change **"c/Mono-2.11.2/bin"** to **"i/Mono-2.11.2/bin"**

```
PATH=.:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/cygdrive/i/Mono-2.11.2/bin
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=.:/lib/pkgconfig:/cygdrive/i/Mono-2.11.2/lib/pkgconfig
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/cygdrive/i/Mono-2.11.2/lib
export PATH PKG_CONFIG_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I placed my mono source under the folder specified: **/usr/src/mono/**

So my dirs looks like:

```
i:
i:\cygwin\
i:\cygwin\usr\src\mono
i:\cygwin\usr\src\mono\mono
i:\cygwin\usr\src\mono\mcs  etc   etc
i:\Mono-2.11.2\bin etc
```

Now the instructions says I must change dirs to /usr/src/mono/mono and run **"./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local"** from the cygwin terminal

However that doesnt work. Running the above command from  **/usr/src/mono/** works fine.

Now heres the problem. The next instruction is to run **"make"**. However this comes up with :

```
$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I even tried running it from the /usr/src/mono/mono dir. Still no luck. 
Can someone please suggest what I should do to be able to build the mono source on windows 7?

```
Update:  
I needed to install the **gnu c++ compiler (g++)**. I just ran the cygwin setup again, searched for g++ and installed that. The autogen.sh ran to completion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last lines of `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local` output should
look like bellow with `Now type make to compile` at the end. And it
generats `Makefile` in the same directory.

I think in your case `./autogen.sh` failed. You can keep a log file
and check what it is complaining about.

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local 2>&1 | tee autogen.log
```

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system

The end of the `./autogen.sh` ouptut:

```
config.status: executing quiet-libtool commands
config.status: executing default commands

        mcs source:    mcs
        olive source:  

   Engine:
    GC:        sgen and bundled Boehm GC with typed GC and parallel mark
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGALTSTACK:   yes
    Engine:        Building and using the JIT
    oprofile:      no
    BigArrays:     no
    DTrace:        no
    LLVM Back End: no (dynamically loaded: no)

    Libraries:
    Moon Profile:  no (boehm)
    MonoDroid:     no
    MonoTouch:     no
    Mobile:        no
    JNI support:   IKVM Native
    libgdiplus:    assumed to be installed
    zlib:          system zlib


Now type `make' to compile
```

Comment: This is the last few lines from the output

checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/usr/src/mono':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details

I'll download the cpp package and let you know how it goes

Comment: I needed to install the gnu c++ compiler (g++)
I'm giving you the points for suggesting that autogenfails and to inspect a log